# python error on struct.unpack

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and I am trying to use unpack like this:

```
data = f.read(4)
AAA=len(data)
BBB=struct.calcsize(cformat)
print AAA
print BBB
value = struct.unpack(cformat, data)
return value[0]
```

This runs fine as long as AAA == BBB but sometimes, f.read only reads 3 bytes and then I get an error.  The actual value in the file that I am trying to read is 26.  It reads all of the values from 1-221 except for 26 where it errors because f.read(size) only reads three bytes

Comment: You have described what happens and why. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question is "How should I read a 26 without an error?"

First check the arguments to the `open()` that produces `f`. Under Windows, unless you open a file in binary mode (`f = open(filename, "rb")`), Python assumes that the file is a text file. Windows treats byte value 26 (Ctrl+Z) in a text file as an end-of-file marker, a quirk that it [inherited from CP/M](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/16/90448.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have opened a binary file in text mode, and you are using an operating system where the distinction matters. Try adding `b` to the mode parameter when you open the file:

```
f = open("my_input_file.bin", "rb")
```